# TypeError: default_get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) - Odoov8 to Odoov10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this method

```
@api.model
def default_get(self, field_list): 
    """ Get default values
    @param fields: List of fields for default value
    """
    # NOTE: use field_list argument instead of fields for fix the pylint
    # error W0621 Redefining name 'fields' from outer scope
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).default_get(
        field_list) 
    if self._context.get('active_id'):
        code = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%Y')
        period_obj = self.env['account.period']
        period_ids = period_obj.search([('code', '=', code)]
                                       ) 
        period_id = period_ids and period_ids[0]

        res.update({'period': period_id})
    return res
```

This method is declared on a class which inherits `account.invoice.refund`, so this class has this method on it, but when I click on Refund Invoice it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: default_get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The problem is that for example the arguments `self, field_list` field_list actually I don't know why it's there, I even looked for this on v8 accounting modules but it doesn't exist, less on v10, this method originally was like this:

```
    def default_get(self, cr, uid, field_list, context=None):
    """ Get default values
    @param fields: List of fields for default value
    """
    # NOTE: use field_list argument instead of fields for fix the pylint
    # error W0621 Redefining name 'fields' from outer scope
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).default_get(
        cr, uid, field_list, context=context)
    if context.get('active_id'):
        code = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%Y')
        period_obj = self.pool.get('account.period')
        period_ids = period_obj.search(cr, uid, [('code', '=', code)],
                                       context=context)
        period_id = period_ids and period_ids[0]

        res.update({'period': period_id})
    return res
```

I think that argument `field_list` is unnecessary, I could be wrong.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

**EDIT**

The complete class looks like this:

```
class AccountInvoiceRefund(models.TransientModel):

"""Refunds invoice"""

_inherit = 'account.invoice.refund'

nro_ctrl = fields.Char(
    'Control Number', size=32,
    help="Code used for intern invoice control")
loc_req = fields.Boolean(
    string='Required by Localization',
    default=lambda s: s._get_loc_req(),
    help='This fields is for technical use')

@api.model
def default_get(self, field_list): #, cr, uid, field_list, context=None
    """ Get default values
    @param fields: List of fields for default value
    """
    # NOTE: use field_list argument instead of fields for fix the pylint
    # error W0621 Redefining name 'fields' from outer scope
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).default_get(
        field_list) #cr, uid, field_list, context=context
    if self._context.get('active_id'):
        code = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%Y')
        period_obj = self.env['account.period']
        period_ids = period_obj.search([('code', '=', code)]
                                       ) #cr, uid, [('code', '=', code)], context=context
        period_id = period_ids and period_ids[0]

        res.update({'period': period_id})
    return res

def _get_loc_req(self): #, cr, uid, context=None
    """Get if a field is required or not by a Localization
    @param uid: Integer value of the user
    """
    #context = context or {}
    res = False
    rc_obj = self.env['res.company']
    ru_brw = self.env['res.users'].browse() #cr, uid, uid, context=context
    rc_brw = rc_obj.browse(ru_brw.company_id.id) #cr, uid, ru_brw.company_id.id, context=context
    if rc_brw.country_id and rc_brw.country_id.code == 'VE':
        res = True
    return res

def _get_journal(self): #, cr, uid, context=None
    """ Return journal depending of the invoice type
    """
    obj_journal = self.env['account.journal']
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    journal = obj_journal.search([('type_', '=', 'sale_refund')]) #cr, uid, [('type_', '=', 'sale_refund')]
    if self._context.get('type_', False):
        if context['type_'] in ('in_invoice', 'in_refund'):
            journal = obj_journal.search(
                [('type_', '=', 'purchase_refund')]) # cr, uid, [('type_', '=', 'purchase_refund')]
    return journal and journal[0] or False

def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type=False,
                    toolbar=False, submenu=False): #cr, uid, context=None
    """ Depending on context, options are displayed in the selection field
    """
    #context = dict(context or {})
    journal_obj = self.env['account.journal']
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
        toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu) #cr, uid, -  context=context,
    journal_type = self._context.get('journal_type', 'sale_refund')
    if journal_type in ('sale', 'sale_refund'):
        journal_type = 'sale_refund'
    else:
        journal_type = 'purchase_refund'
    for field in res['fields']:
        if field == 'journal_id':
            journal_select = journal_obj._name_search(
                '', [('type', '=', journal_type)],
                limit=None, name_get_uid=1) #cr, uid, - context=context, 
            res['fields'][field]['selection'] = journal_select
    return res

def _get_orig(self, inv, ref): #, cr, uid, inv, ref, context=None
    """ Return  default origin value
    """
    #context = context or {}
    nro_ref = ref
    if inv.type == 'out_invoice':
        nro_ref = inv.number
    orig = ('Devolucion FACT:' + (nro_ref or '') +
            '- DE FECHA:' + (inv.date_invoice or '') +
            (' TOTAL:' + str(inv.amount_total) or ''))
    return orig

def cn_iva_validate(self, invoice): #cr, uid, invoice, context=None
    """
    Validates if retentions have been changes to move the state confirmed
    and done
    """
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    ret_iva_id = False
    ret_islr_id = False
    im_obj = self.env['ir.model']
    res = im_obj.browse(cr, uid, im_obj.search(
        [('model', '=', 'account.invoice')]), #cr, uid, [('model', '=', 'account.invoice')], context=context
        )[0].field_id #context=context)[0].field_id
    for i in res:
        if i.name == 'wh_iva_id':
            if invoice.wh_iva_id:
                ret_iva_id = invoice.wh_iva_id.id
        if i.name == 'islr_wh_doc_id':
            if invoice.islr_wh_doc_id:
                ret_islr_id = invoice.islr_wh_doc_id.id

    awi_obj = self.env['account.wh.iva']
    iwd_obj = self.env['islr.wh.doc']
    wf_service = workflow

    if ret_iva_id:
        awi_obj.compute_amount_wh([ret_iva_id]) #cr, uid, [ret_iva_id], context=context
        wf_service.trg_validate('account.wh.iva', ret_iva_id,
                                'wh_iva_confirmed') # uid, 'account.wh.iva', ret_iva_id, 'wh_iva_confirmed', cr
        wf_service.trg_validate('account.wh.iva', ret_iva_id,
                                'wh_iva_done') #uid, 'account.wh.iva', ret_iva_id, 'wh_iva_done', cr

    if ret_islr_id:
        iwd_obj.action_confirm1([ret_islr_id]) #cr, uid, [ret_islr_id], context=context
        wf_service.trg_validate('islr.wh.doc', ret_islr_id,
                                'act_done') #uid, 'islr.wh.doc', ret_islr_id, 'act_done', cr

    return True

@api.multi
def compute_refund(self, mode='refund'): #cr, uid, ids, mode='refund', context=None
    """
    @param ids: the account invoice refund’s ID or list of IDs
    """
    wzd_brw = self.browse() #cr, uid, ids[0], context=context
    inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
    reconcile_obj = self.env['account.move.reconcile']
    account_m_line_obj = self.env['account.move.line']
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    act_obj = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
    wf_service = workflow
    inv_tax_obj = self.env['account.invoice.tax']
    inv_line_obj = self.env['account.invoice.line']
    res_users_obj = self.env['res.users']
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    for form in self.read(): #cr, uid, ids, context=context
        created_inv = []
        date = False
        period = False
        description = False
        nroctrl = False
        company = res_users_obj.browse().company_id  #cr, uid, uid, context=context
        journal_brw = form.get('journal_id', False)
        for inv in inv_obj.browse(self._context.get('active_ids')): # cr, uid, context=context
            if inv.state in ['draft', 'proforma2', 'cancel']:
                raise UserError(
                    _('Error !'),
                    _('Can not %s draft/proforma/cancel invoice.') % (
                        mode))
            if inv.reconciled and mode in ('cancel', 'modify'):
                raise UserError(
                    _('Error !'),
                    _('Can not %s invoice which is already reconciled,'
                      ' invoice should be unreconciled first. You can only'
                      ' Refund this invoice') % (mode))
            period = form.get('period') and form.get('period')[0] or False
            if not period:
                    # Take period from the current date
                period = self.env['account.period'].find() #cr, uid, context=context
                period = period and period[0] or False
                if not period:
                    raise UserError(
                        _('No Pediod Defined'),
                        _('You have been left empty the period field that'
                          ' automatically fill with the current period.'
                          ' However there is not period defined for the'
                          ' current company. Please check in'
                          ' Accounting/Configuration/Periods'))
                self.write({'period': period}) #cr, uid, ids, {'period': period}, context=context

            if not journal_brw:
                journal_id = inv.journal_id.id
            else:
                journal_id = journal_brw[0]

            if form['date']:
                date = form['date']
                if not form['period']:
                    self.env.cr.execute("select name from ir_model_fields \
                                        where model = 'account.period' \
                                        and name = 'company_id'")
                    result_query = self.env.cr.fetchone()
                    if result_query:
                        self.env.cr.execute(
                            "select p.id "
                            "from account_fiscalyear y, account_period p "
                            "where y.id=p.fiscalyear_id and date(%s)"
                            " between p.date_start AND p.date_stop and"
                            " y.company_id = %s limit 1""", (
                                date, company.id,))
                    else:
                        self.env.cr.execute("""SELECT id
                                    from account_period where date(%s)
                                    between date_start AND  date_stop  \
                                    limit 1 """, (date,))
                    res = self.env.cr.fetchone()
                    if res:
                        period = res[0]
            else:
                # Take current date
                # date = inv.date_invoice
                date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if form['description']:
                description = form['description']
            else:
                description = inv.name

            if inv.type in ('in_invoice', 'in_refund'):
                if form['nro_ctrl']:
                    nroctrl = form['nro_ctrl']
                else:
                    raise UserError(
                        _('Control Number !'),
                        _('Missing Control Number on Invoice Refund!'))

            if not period:
                raise UserError(_('Data Insufficient !'),
                                     _('No Period found on Invoice!'))

            refund_id = inv_obj.refund([inv.id], date, period, description, journal_id) #cr, uid, [inv.id], date, period, description, journal_id

            refund = inv_obj.browse(refund_id[0]) #cr, uid, refund_id[0], context=context
            # Add parent invoice
            self.env.cr.execute(
                "update account_invoice set date_due='%s',nro_ctrl='%s',"
                " check_total='%s', parent_id=%s where id =%s" % (
                    date, nroctrl, inv.check_total, inv.id, refund.id))
            inv_obj.button_compute(refund_id) #cr, uid, refund_id

            created_inv.append(refund_id[0])
            if mode in ('cancel', 'modify'):
                movelines = inv.move_id.line_id
                to_reconcile_ids = {}
                for line in movelines:
                    if line.account_id.id == inv.account_id.id:
                        to_reconcile_ids[line.account_id.id] = [line.id]
                    if not isinstance(line.reconcile_id,
                                      osv.orm.browse_null):
                        reconcile_obj.unlink(line.reconcile_id.id) #cr, uid, line.reconcile_id.id
                wf_service.trg_validate('account.invoice', refund.id, 'invoice_open') #uid, 'account.invoice', refund.id, 'invoice_open', cr

                refund = inv_obj.browse(refund_id[0]) #cr, uid, refund_id[0], context=context
                self.cn_iva_validate(refund) #cr, uid, refund, context=context

                for tmpline in refund.move_id.line_id:
                    if tmpline.account_id.id == inv.account_id.id:
                        to_reconcile_ids[tmpline.account_id.id].append(
                            tmpline.id)
                for account in to_reconcile_ids:
                    account_m_line_obj.reconcile(
                        cr, uid, to_reconcile_ids[account],
                        writeoff_period_id=period,
                        writeoff_journal_id=inv.journal_id.id,
                        writeoff_acc_id=inv.account_id.id)
            if mode == 'modify':
                invoice = inv_obj.read(
                    [inv.id], [
                        'name', 'type', 'number',
                        'supplier_invoice_number', 'comment', 'date_due',
                        'partner_id', 'partner_insite', 'partner_contact',
                        'partner_ref', 'payment_term', 'account_id',
                        'currency_id', 'invoice_line', 'tax_line',
                        'journal_id', 'period_id'],
                    ) #cr, uid, [inv.id], context=context
                invoice = invoice[0]
                del invoice['id']
                invoice_lines = inv_line_obj.browse(
                    invoice['invoice_line']) #cr, uid, invoice['invoice_line'], context=context

                invoice_lines = inv_obj._refund_cleanup_lines(
                    invoice_lines) #cr, uid, invoice_lines
                tax_lines = inv_tax_obj.browse(
                    invoice['tax_line']) #cr, uid, invoice['tax_line'], context=context
                tax_lines = inv_obj._refund_cleanup_lines(
                    tax_lines) #cr, uid, tax_lines
                # Add origin value
                orig = self._get_orig(
                    inv, invoice['supplier_invoice_number'],
                    ) #cr, uid, inv, invoice['supplier_invoice_number'],  context
                invoice.update({
                    'type': inv.type,
                    'date_invoice': date,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'number': False,
                    'invoice_line': invoice_lines,
                    'tax_line': tax_lines,
                    'period_id': period,
                    'name': description,
                    'origin': orig,

                })
                for field in ('partner_id', 'account_id', 'currency_id',
                              'payment_term', 'journal_id'):
                    invoice[field] = invoice[field] and invoice[field][0]
                inv_id = inv_obj.create(invoice, {}) #cr, uid, invoice, {}
                if inv.payment_term.id:
                    data = inv_obj.onchange_payment_term_date_invoice(
                        [inv_id], inv.payment_term.id, date) #cr, uid, [inv_id], inv.payment_term.id, date
                    if 'value' in data and data['value']:
                        inv_obj.write([inv_id], data['value']) #cr, uid, [inv_id], data['value']
                created_inv.append(inv_id)

                new_inv_brw = inv_obj.browse(created_inv[1]) #cr, uid, created_inv[1], context=context
                inv_obj.write(
                    created_inv[0],
                    {'name': wzd_brw.description,
                     'origin': new_inv_brw.origin}) #cr, uid, created_inv[0], - 'origin': new_inv_brw.origin}, context=context
                inv_obj.write(
                    created_inv[1],
                    {'origin': inv.origin,
                     'name': wzd_brw.description}) #cr, uid, created_inv[1], - 'name': wzd_brw.description}, context=context
            if inv.type in ('out_invoice', 'out_refund'):
                xml_id = 'action_invoice_tree3'
                # if hasattr(inv, 'sale_ids'):
                # for i in inv.sale_ids:
                # cr.execute('insert into sale_order_invoice_rel
                # (order_id,invoice_id) values (%s,%s)', (i.id,
                # refund_id[0]))
            else:
                xml_id = 'action_invoice_tree4'
            result = mod_obj.get_object_reference('account', xml_id) #cr, uid, 'account', xml_id
            xml_id = result and result[1] or False
            result = act_obj.read(xml_id) #cr, uid, xml_id, context=context
            invoice_domain = ast.literal_eval(result['domain'])
            invoice_domain.append(('id', 'in', created_inv))
            result['domain'] = invoice_domain

            if wzd_brw.filter_refund == 'cancel':
                orig = self._get_orig(inv,
                                      inv.supplier_invoice_number) #cr, uid, inv, inv.supplier_invoice_number, context
                inv_obj.write(created_inv[0],
                              {'origin': orig,
                               'name': wzd_brw.description},
                              ) #cr, uid, created_inv[0], - context=context

            elif wzd_brw.filter_refund == 'refund':
                orig = self._get_orig(inv,
                                      inv.supplier_invoice_number) #cr, uid, inv, inv.supplier_invoice_number, context
                inv_obj.write(created_inv[0],
                              {'origin': inv.origin,
                               'name': wzd_brw.description},
                              ) #context=context cr, uid, 
        return result

@api.multi
def validate_total_payment_inv(self): #, cr, uid, ids, context=None
    """ Method that validate if invoice is totally paid.
    @param ids: list of invoices.
    return: True: if invoice is paid.
            False: if invoice is not paid.
    """
    res = False
    inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
    for inv in inv_obj.browse(): #cr, uid, ids, context=context
        res = inv.reconciled
    return res

@api.multi
def validate_wh(self): #, cr, uid, ids, context=None
    """ Method that validate if invoice has non-yet processed withholds.

    return: True: if invoice is does not have wh's or it does have and
                  those ones are validated.
            False: if invoice is does have and those wh's are not yet
                   validated.

    in the meantime this function is DUMMY,
    and the developer should use it to override and get advantage of it.
    """
    return True

def unreconcile_paid_invoices(self, invoiceids): #cr, uid, invoiceids, context=None
    """ Method that unreconcile the payments of invoice.
    @param invoiceids: list of invoices.
    return: True: unreconcile successfully.
            False: unreconcile unsuccessfully.
    """
    inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
    moveline_obj = self.env['account.move.line']
    voucher_pool = self.env['account.voucher']
    res = True
    rec = []
    mid = []
    if self.validate_total_payment_inv(invoiceids): # cr, uid, context=context
        for inv in inv_obj.browse(invoiceids): #cr, uid, invoiceids, context=context
            movelineids = inv_obj.move_line_id_payment_get([inv.id]) #cr, uid
            for moveline in moveline_obj.browse(movelineids): #cr, uid, movelineids, context=context
                if moveline.reconcile_id:
                    rec += [moveline.reconcile_id.id]
                if moveline.reconcile_partial_id:
                    rec += [moveline.reconcile_partial_id.id]
            movelines = moveline_obj.search([('|'), ('reconcile_id', 'in', rec),
                 ('reconcile_partial_id', 'in', rec)]) #cr, uid, context=context
            for mids in moveline_obj.browse(movelines): # cr, uid, movelines, context=context
                mid += [mids.move_id.id]
            voucherids = voucher_pool.search([('move_id', 'in', mid)]) #cr, uid
        if voucherids:
            voucher_pool.cancel_voucher(voucherids) #cr, uid, voucherids, context=context
        else:
            res = False
    return res

@api.multi
def invoice_refund(self): #, cr, uid, ids, context=None
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
    period_obj = self.env['account.period']
    wzr_brw = self.browse()[0] #cr, uid, ids, context=context
    date = wzr_brw.date and wzr_brw.date.split('-')
    period = wzr_brw and wzr_brw.period and wzr_brw.period.id
    period_ids = date and len(date) == 3 and period_obj.search(
        [('code', '=', '%s/%s' % (date[1], date[0]))],
        ) #cr, uid, context=context
    if period not in period_ids:
        raise UserError(
            _('Error !'),
            _('The date should be chosen to belong to the period'))
    if not self.validate_wh(self._context.get('active_ids')): #cr, uid, context=context
        inv = inv_obj.browse(self._context.get('active_ids'),
                             )[0] #cr, uid, context=context
        raise UserError(
            _('Error !'),
            _('There are non-valid withholds for the document %s which'
              ' refund is being processed!' % inv and
              inv.wh_iva_id.code or "vacio"))
    self.unreconcile_paid_invoices(self._context.get('active_ids'),
                                   ) #cr, uid, context=context
    data_refund = self.browse()[0].filter_refund #cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0].filter_refund
    return self.compute_refund(data_refund) #cr, uid, ids, data_refund, context=context
```

Comment: could you put the code of the class because there is nothing wrong with you declaration

Comment: Yes `default_get` is ok. The call or earlier seems to be the problem.

Comment: Hi, edited my question with the full class, Thank You

Comment: I'm thinking about refactoring all debit and refund logic on this module, since on v8 and earlier versions, these methods weren't available by default on Odoo, so I think most of them are (probably) unnecessary on v9 and v10, that's my view of it

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good to me.

I think you should check your class declaration.

Try with following.

```
from odoo import models

class YourClassName(models.Model)
```

NOTE:

If your base class is pop-up window then we need to change from *models.Model* to *models.TransientModel*

Comment: Hi Odedra, no it has to be TransientModel because the class that inherits it's a TransientModel ie: 'account.invoice.refund'